# c# - Entity Framework 6 Error "Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Delete'."

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a code first EF 6 model. I am trying To remove a specified range of data with RemoveRange() and then using SaveChanges() on the entity.

```
customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local.RemoveRange(subjLocal); // subjLocal is not important to the question
customerContext.SaveChanges();
```

I get this message when I step over the SaveChanges method:
[image]

So I view the inner exception and see the message

```
  Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Delete'.
```

I don't see how that can be though when I create all the stored procedures in my base entity with the onModelCreating method:

```
public partial class CustomerContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomerContext()
        : base("name=CustomerContext")
    {
    }

    public CustomerContext(string connStr) : base(connStr) 
    {
    
    }

    public virtual DbSet<RosterSummaryData_Cluster_Local> RosterSummaryData_Cluster_Local { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local> RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RosterSummaryData_Cluster_Local_Bands> RosterSummaryData_Cluster_Local_Bands { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Bands> RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Bands { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RosterSummaryData_Cluster_Local_Averages> RosterSummaryData_Cluster_Local_Averages { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Averages> RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Averages { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<RosterSummaryData_Cluster_Local>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        modelBuilder.Entity<RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        modelBuilder.Entity<RosterSummaryData_Cluster_Local_Bands>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        modelBuilder.Entity<RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Bands>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        modelBuilder.Entity<RosterSummaryData_Cluster_Local_Averages>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        modelBuilder.Entity<RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Averages>().MapToStoredProcedures();
    }
}
```

Here is the code that instantiates the base context:

```
CustomerContext customerContext = new CustomerContext(statsInfo.CustomerDCS); 
//statsInfo.CustomerDCS is just the custom connection string for my entity
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong here or have any experience with this problem because I see no issues and could not find any answers on the internet...

**EDIT**: The stored procedures are definitely not being created, but I see nothing wrong in the code and I have proper permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error EF can't find the stored procedure. Can you confirm that the stored procedure is indeed created in your database? It may be that you do not have permissions on the database to create stored procedures.

Also you are using the default migration option CreateDatabaseIfNotExists. If the database exists already it will not create your objects. Consider using DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges or DropCreateDatabaseAlways. This will drop your database everytime the database changes so you will have to write a migration script to repopulate the data in your dev environment. Please see the code sample below

```
public CustomerContext(string connStr) : base(connStr) 
{
    Database.SetInitializer<CustomerContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CustomerContext>());
}
```

Comment: Well its definitely not being created in the db, but I am 100% sure I have the proper permissions.

Comment: What EF Migration strategy are you using? It could be that EF is not detecting any changes in your model and not creating the stored procs.

Comment: What do you mean by EF migration strategy? All I know is that it is a code first model and I am connecting to the database using the custom connection string constructor and all the modelBuilder code that should create the stored procedures is in the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please make sure that if the Stored Procedure is present in your database, then check the Procedure name contains the schema name "dbo." for example.
This problem sometimes occurs with the presence of the stored procedure also DbUpdate fails as it cannot find, for this please change the Stored procedure name and try again. I hope it will work.
Thanks.

Comment: The stored procedures are not being created, but I don't see why because there are no issues with my code and I have the proper permissions. Any ideas?

Comment: RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Delete do you think the names match??

Comment: I don't understand what your question is?